# How can I multiply table?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tabs

I'm asking for help in one of my JAVA projects. I need to multiply one table into nine. Below I attach picture which better explains my problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTUXK.png

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I understand asking for help finding a bug in existing code, but StackOverflow is not the right place to ask people to solve your homework from scratch...

Comment: Hmm, actually im trying to solve "The game of life" problem and I couldn't figure it out how to multiply tables. And that's not my homework, I'm treating Java as hobby and I'm still learning. You can try to change my mind, but isn't the StackOverflow a forum where you can explain your doubts and learn sth from other more advanced users ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to multiply your your table.

```
int k = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
    System.out.print(k++ + " ");
      if(j % 3 == 0)
      {
        k -= 3;
      }
  }
  k += 3;
  if(i % 3 == 0)
  {
    k = 1;
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Yes, It worked very well. Thank you so much for you help ! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run the loop for n*n where n is the count of row or column.

```
        int n = 3;
        int[][] arr = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
        int[][] result = new int[n*n][n*n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n * n; j++) {
                result[i][j] = arr[i%n][j%n];
            }
        }
```

Put the values from the original array based on the index.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. So simple and very powerful. Thank you so much !.